# How do I format zsh code (something like prettier / shfmt)?

Tags: zsh, prettier, formatter

For `bash` and `sh`, there is [`shfmt`](https://github.com/mvdan/sh).

How do I format `zsh` code?

I'd like to be able to set some options like in `shfmt`, ie:

```
  -i uint   indent: 0 for tabs (default), >0 for number of spaces
  -bn       binary ops like && and | may start a line
  -ci       switch cases will be indented
  -sr       redirect operators will be followed by a space
  -kp       keep column alignment paddings
  -fn       function opening braces are placed on a separate line
```

[`zsh-hist`](https://github.com/marlonrichert/zsh-hist) says it supports "uniform code formatting", but I can't work out how to run it from the command line and it's main purpose is history manipulation.

How do I format `zsh` code either in the shell or via something like VSCode prettier?

Comment: Are you searching for a pretty-printer for zsh, similar to shfmt for bash, or are you going to write your own pretty-printer?

Comment: I'm looking for a method to format `zsh` code without writing a tool from scratch.

Comment: Perhaps you could start by taking `shfmt` as a base, and create from this your own formatter? Since zsh and bash are syntactically quite similar in spirit, this should be much less work than starting from scratch.

Comment: Could you share an example fie you're trying to format?

Comment: While it's still not implemented (as of Jan 2023), this issue on shfmt by the author from 2021 sounds like there is interest in implementing support for it: https://github.com/mvdan/sh/issues/120#issuecomment-903077180